Prevent Visual Studio 2022 from autocompleting html on > or space
I am using Visual Studio 2022 with the Resharper plugin. I am unsure which of these two is causing the issue.
I am working on a Razor Page in a Blazor project (.razor file)
I start typing an html element. eg 
I type <td

and I get several suggestions.
When I then press > my IDE changes < td> into the IntelliSense item.
e.g.
< td > becomes < EventDetails>< /EventDetails>

